# Grub2 fails to load on an AMD cpu

Tags: boot, grub2, grub, boot-loader

I have built a linux image with GRUB2 as its boot loader and written it on an IDE hard disk. When I put it in a computer with Intel cpu, it works fine. But putting it in an AMD cpu computer, it even fails to detect the HDD and raises the following error:

```
Not found any [active partition] in HDD
DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER
```

Also I have tested with grub-legacy, it again works fine. SO it seems that GRUB 1.9* is not compatible with maybe old AMD CPUs.

Please note that the PC under test spec is as follows:

```
CPU TYPE: AMD-K6(tm)-2
CPU-CLOCK: 300
Pri- Master Disk: LBA, UDMA 33, 1040MB
```

Also note that I have tested in two systems, (two INTEL and two AMD), and still same result.

Comment: How did you copy it?  Did you copy the MBR and the space between the MBR and first partition too?